# Get time from Psql to Highstock

Tags: javascript, postgresql, time, highcharts

I am trying to get time from postgresql database to Highstock series, so in my series I put that code :

```
series: [{
    name: "DNS hits",
    data: [
    <%
    @HighStock_result.each{ |row|
    %>
    [Date.UTC(<%= row["query_time"] %>)],
    <%}%>
    ],
}]
```

in my database I have column query_time type timestamp without time zone, the format of time is like this :

```
2014-04-30 11:01:55
2014-04-30 11:01:56
2014-04-30 11:01:56
2014-04-30 11:01:57
```

So when run this I have a javascript error :

```
Horodatage : 05/05/2014 11:28:53
Erreur : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
Fichier Source : http://192.168.111.136:3000/assets/js/lib/all-concat.js?body=1
Ligne : 1909, Colonne : 25
Code Source :
[Date.UTC(2014-04-30 11:01:55)],
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you add array of dates in Date.UTC or single line? I advice to familiar how date.utc() works, and hope that Date.parse() should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
series: [
    {
        name : 'dns hits',
        data: ([
            <% @HighStock_result.each{ |row| %>
            [Date.UTC(<%=row['qt']%>),<%=row['hits']%>],
            <%}%>
        ])
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need tranform the data. Try to separate the seconds, days, etc with [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). Example:

```
$datatime = mktime($hour, $minute, $sencond, $month, $day, $year)*1000
```

More info for mktime [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Yesterday i used it for create a highstock, i hope help you :)